# SQL query followed by inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I need to run a simple query on a table to find all the rows with a corresponding id. I then want to perform an inner join.

```
 $applications = SELECT * FROM applications WHERE clubid = $_SESSION['id']
```

Once I have got all of the rows which meet this criteria, I then want to perform something along the lines of this. The `$applications`is just someway of storing the rows that were found from the above query.

```
SELECT *
FROM $applications
INNER JOIN productsapplied
ON $applications.ID = productsapplied.appid;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: why the two queries?  Why couldn't you just use ine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this all as one query:

```
SELECT *
FROM applications a INNER JOIN
     productsapplied pa
     ON a.ID = pa.appid
WHERE a.clubid = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine both querys as

```
SELECT * FROM $applications
  INNER JOIN productsapplied
    ON $applications.ID = productsapplied.appid
  WHERE $applications.clubid = $_SESSION['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Create View

```
CREATE VIEW applications AS
 SELECT * FROM applications WHERE clubid = $_SESSION['id']
```

And quoting you

```
SELECT *
FROM applications
INNER JOIN productsapplied
ON applications.ID = productsapplied.appid;
```